# Using CASE as part of a dblink to get data

Tags: sql, oracle, case, dblink

I am attempting to use CASE to return a value from a dblink with a sub query.  However, the results are not displaying what I would expect.  Instead of going through each WHEN, it is returning the value from the first WHEN (even though it doesn't meet the criteria).  I'm sure it has something to do with how I am using CASE with the sub query.

I have ran the sub query by itself, and it returns the expected results.

```
select su.shp_filter as "User_Type", su.shp_access_id as "RAD_ID", su.shp_name as "User_Name", rg.rad_stu_level as "Student_Level",
case
    when su.shp_filter = 'STU' then 
        case
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'HP%' then 'HP'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'AS%' then 'AS'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'BU%' then 'BU'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'ED%' then 'ED'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'TE%' then 'TE'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'UN%' then 'UN'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'KE%' then 'KE'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'PH%' then 'PH'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'OP%' then 'OP'
            when rgd.rad_goal_value like 'CP%' then 'CP'
        end
    when su.shp_filter in ('ADV','REG','DEAN','DEPT','ATHL') then
        case
            when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            join DWSCHEMA.SHP_USER_MST su
            on substr(su.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8)
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '11%') then 'Office 1'
            when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            join DWSCHEMA.SHP_USER_MST su
            on substr(su.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8)
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '21%') then 'Office 2'
            when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            join DWSCHEMA.SHP_USER_MST su
            on substr(su.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8)
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '22%') then 'Office 3'
            when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            join DWSCHEMA.SHP_USER_MST su
            on substr(su.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8)
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '31%') then 'Academic Affairs'
end "College"
```

Comment: It's an Oracle db, and I am using Toad.

Comment: A lot of your query is missing... was that intentional? One of the CASE statements is missing its END.

Comment: It would only allow me to paste so much.  There is actually an END that is not included in the above code that comes before the END "College".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh - I think I see your problem. Your `exists` subqueries aren't joined to your outer query at all, so they're always returning hundreds of rows. This will be more clear if you rename each instance of SHP_USER_MST to su1, su2, su3, etc:

```
when su.shp_filter in ('ADV','REG','DEAN','DEPT','ATHL') then
    case
        when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su1.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            join DWSCHEMA.SHP_USER_MST su1 
            on substr(su1.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8)
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '11%') then 'Office 1'
        when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su2.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            join DWSCHEMA.SHP_USER_MST su2 
            on substr(su2.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8)
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '21%') then 'Office 2'
```

If you look here, nothing in the subquery is referencing the current row in `su` - so you're checking whether ANY users exist in your subquery. And they always do, so it always returns 'Office 1'.

I think you want something more like

```
when su.shp_filter in ('ADV','REG','DEAN','DEPT','ATHL') then
    case
        when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and substr(su.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8) -- Link subquery to outer query
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '11%') then 'Office 1'
        when exists (select pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home, su.shp_access_id, spriden.spriden_id from pebempl@dblink pebempl
            join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
            on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
            where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
            and substr(su.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8) -- Link subquery to outer query
            and pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home like '21%') then 'Office 2'
...etc
```

I think that should work for you, but as an additional suggestion, I think you could also rewrite that section to be a bit more efficient and readable.

```
case (select substr(min(pebempl.pebempl_orgn_code_home),1,2) from pebempl@dblink pebempl
        join spriden@gold.ferris.edu spriden
        on pebempl.pebempl_pidm=spriden.spriden_pidm
        where spriden.spriden_change_ind is null
        and substr(su.shp_access_id,1,8) = substr(spriden.SPRIDEN_ID,1,8))
    when '11' then 'Office 1'
    when '21' then 'Office 2'
    when '22' then 'Office 3'
    when '31' then 'Academic Affairs'
end
```

Comment: That did the trick.  It also reduce the length of the query, which is good.  I thought I had tried something similar, but apparently not.